# Kibana fails to start with Shield configured over HTTP

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, elasticsearch-plugin, elastic-shield

I installed Shield in my Elastic Search cluster and configured Kibana to work with it as described: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/kibana.html 
No I restart Kibana and get this error:

> {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2016-02-15T19:58:22+00:00","tags":["fatal"],"pid":28422,"level":"fatal","message":"HTTPS
>   is required. Please set server.ssl.key and server.ssl.cert in kiban$
>   FATAL { [Error: HTTPS is required. Please set server.ssl.key and
>   server.ssl.cert in kibana.yml.]   cause: [Error: HTTPS is required.
>   Please set server.ssl.key and server.ssl.cert in kibana.yml.],
>   isOperational: true }

Tutorial above doesn't state that HTTP is mandatory for Kibana to work with Shield but the error does. Any idea whether I can still use Shield with Kibana without setting up SSL?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is the case in the currently release of Kibana (4.4). In `installedPlugins/shield/index.js:38:13` one can conclude that there is no way to get around using HTTPS when this plugin is enabled. If you simply skip the step by removing the Shield plugin for Kibana with `bin/kibana plugin --remove shield`, Kibana will be usable again with browser authentication, but this is NOT for production purposes IMO.

Answer (score 1):

add this in in kibana.yml, but only do it if you have SSL configured in some other way, eg a load balancer with SSL termination

```
shield.skipSslCheck: true
```

Comment: Thanks Risto. You saved me from a lot of trouble.